# My question was closed as a duplicate, but I still need help. What can I do?

Tags: support, faq

My question has been closed as a duplicate. However, I'm having trouble with the answers to that other question. What can I do now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions that are closed needn't stay closed. You're encouraged to edit your original question to explain why the answers on the duplicate don't help you; this can lead to your question being reopened. If you think that you've edited it enough to be distinct from the duplicate, you can flag it for moderator attention and one of the moderators can reopen it.

(The community also has the power to reopen it: it takes 5 votes to do so or one from a moderator. Given that people are probably less aware that a question is awaiting being reopened than they are of one that is in the process of being closed, I think that flagging for moderator attention is easier and absolutely fine in this case.)

Comment: I just realized that there's a major problem with this answer: You need 15 rep if you want to flag for moderator attention! This was [discussed on meta.math.sx](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1917/2575) and lead to a [feature request on meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86245/flag-ones-own-question-without-reputation-limit). What do you think?

Comment: @Hendrik: You're right.  What other ways of attracting attention are there?  There's using the @ syntax, but that only works if a moderator has left a comment on the question.  Can't post a question here with no rep, what about chat?  I guess the last-ditch method is to include a plea in the edited question, since it gets bumped to the top then _someone_ will see it!

Comment: @Hendrik: Just asked for information on that, as it seems a good entry in the unofficial FAQ.

Comment: Isn't there some minimial rep of 10 to go to the chat?