# Why do some users have no profiles?

Tags: discussion

I was reading the following question: [LaTeX images formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76486/latex-images-formatting)

There, the user that has asked the question, a user named `Vartec` (who apparently to me has provided the correct answer) have no profiles. I tried clicking on their names, but that doesn't redirect me to their profiles.

Why do some users have no profiles? What rep do they have?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why do some users have no profiles?

This specific question stems from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), and the [original poster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64392/user64392) (OP) is not registered on TeX.SE. When migrated, their profile image shows up as a generic/greyed-out image.

We typically post one of our [Text building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430/5764) requesting the user to register.

> What rep do they have?

Once they register on this site, you'll be able to view their TeX.SE profile. Their starting reputation will be 101 - referred to an [*Association Bonus*](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) of 100 plus the default 1 rep, but they will also inherit additional reputation bestowed on posts on TeX.SE.

Comment: Note that one only gets the association bonus if one has at least 200 reputation on at least one other Stack Exchange site.