# community bot rejects an appropriate edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

Why would community bot reject a [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25602) formatting edit that should have been approved ?

[image]

Comment: @texenthusiast the editor removed all the extra blank lines, added 2 back ticks, and then formatted the code.  That is about 20-25 separate moves.

Comment: @texenthusiast it just seems to be an odd/weird rejection.

Comment: very peculiar.  a few days ago i made a similar edit to [Preventing the “end square” of proof environment to be alone on a newpage after an enumeration](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128018/579) and it wasn't rejected.  (a subsequent edit -- of only 1 character -- was made to fix something i missed, and that also wasn't rejected.)

Answer (score 5):

From [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163766/168244): User [Community](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) rejects an edit "when the post owner or someone with [2000+ rep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) makes an edit and the suggested edit is still being reviewed."

In this particular case, user [Adam](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/32888/adam)'s [suggested edit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25602) was most certainly valid, since [we encourage code formatting in posts](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430/5764). However, according to the [post revision history](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/128251/revisions), the following sequence of events ensued (some guess-work):

- 18:35:02 - User [Adam](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/32888/adam) suggests an edit
- 18:35:24 - User [dustin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27081/dustin) approves the edit
- 18:35:36 - User [dustin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27081/dustin) initiates an edit to the post ("someone with 2000+ rep" while the suggested edit is still pending)
- 18:36:13 - User [dustin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27081/dustin) saves the edit, retroactively causing an edit rejection by user [Community](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) @ 18:35:36

Underlying here is the fact that a suggested edit isn't immediately incorporated once approved by someone reviewing the queue entry. Instead, (at least) two votes are required. See [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/168244)

Comment: I edited the post after I saw the rejection not before.

Comment: I think I know what may have happened.  When I went to click approve, I hit edit but didn't edit.  I hit the back button and clicked approve.  Then the community rejected it so I put in Adam's edit afterwords.  Would hitting edit and not editing to only go back to approve cause this?

Comment: @dustin: Not sure, since I haven't mis-clicked in such a fashion before. Sleuthing helps...