# Short Link to the Duckboat

Tags: feature-request

I think it would be helpful to have a shorthand link to the duckboat for use in comments, similar to the ones for meta and faq and the like.

This would encourage the linking of the article to help new users in a fun way, and get them used to the community here.

I'll be posting links to it, I'd just find it more convenient if there was a short link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

short link:

[The DuckBoat -- News from TeX.SE: Asking effective questions](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-3/tb120duck.pdf)

```
[The DuckBoat -- News from TeX.SE: Asking effective questions](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-3/tb120duck.pdf)
```

Comment: I added a "code" version for easy copy & paste. Please feel free to undo the edit if you don't like it.

Comment: *I think nobody on earth has read all of the more than 1,000
pages of the TikZ & PGF manual!* ... Ehm... I'll take my coat...

Comment: Perhaps add it to the "Useful Links" section of [Text building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks)?